# Windows 10 powershell IE 11 object

Tags: powershell, windows-10, internet-explorer-11

Here is the batch code:

```
<# :
  @echo off
    powershell /nop /ex bypass^
    "&{[ScriptBlock]::Create((gc '%~f0') -join [Char]10).Invoke()}"
  exit /b
#>
$ie = new-object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Visible = $false
$ie.Silent = $true
while($ie.Busy -ne $false) {start-sleep -m 100} 
$ie.Navigate2("https://www.google.ru/", 4)
while($ie.Busy -ne $false) {start-sleep -m 100} 
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100}
start-sleep -m 500
$ie.Stop()
echo $ie.Document.body.innerHTML > ".\html.txt"
$ie.Quit()
```

This code works fine in Windows 7 x64, Windows 8 x64, but not work in Windows 10 x64. Microsoft EDGE browser is not using, IE 11 is selected as default browser. I tried to run bat-file as administrator and as invoker.. What is wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What should the script do anyway? What happens and what should happen?

Comment: If all you want to do is collect the HTML of a web page, a desktop web browser is far from an optimal method.

Comment: when i run bat-file with this code it create new file named "html.txt" with html code of page. Other methods to get the same result not interesting for me. One question - why this code not work in Win 10? What should I check/fix to get needed result?

Comment: problem is localized - i bought two new computers, office 365 was pre-installed, after uninstall office this bug is appears. Second computer works fine with this code. Seems office uninstall procedure damages IE. Any ideas? May be I should re-install IE? How can I do this? I do not need Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to retrieve the HTML content of a web page, don't use a web browser at all. Instead, use `invoke-webrequest` and access the `content` property of the resulting object.

```
invoke-webrequest -Uri http://www.google.ru/ | select-object -property content
```